# Issues with script to pull AD group membership and output info to file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have one script that I ran that pulled a list of Active Directory groups that have 1 member in them. This script worked fine and gave me a list of AD groups that I was looking for(the script is below):

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Members | where { $_.Members.Count -eq 1 } | Export-Csv -Path c:\users\me\documents\1_member_groups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Now I'm trying to take this file and feed the list of groups into another script that will pull the membership of these AD groups and place it into a file with the group name and group member listed. I found a nice script that I thought should do what I want but it seems that the group name section is blank when $results are exported. Can anyone make any recommendations or suggest another method to do this?

*** For some reason I haven't had much luck with Import-Csv for the input file, it seems to only work with Get-Content and a txt file which is fine

```
$Groups = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\me\Documents\1_member_groups.txt'

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'

$Results = foreach( $Group in $Groups ){Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | foreach {[pscustomobject]@{GroupName = $Group.NameName = $_.Name}}}

$Results| Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\test1.csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can process everything on one go instead of exporting the result to a file and then read that file to process the second part of your script.

Try something like this, I think it should work:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Member | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Member.Count -eq 1)
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            GroupName = $_.Name
            Member = (Get-ADObject $_.Member).Name
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path c:\users\me\documents\1_member_groups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that I'm doing `(Get-ADUser $_.Member).Name`, in this case, since we are sure that there is only 1 member of the group, it should work fine however if there were more than one member, a loop over this array would be needed.

Comment: You should use `Get-ADObject` instead of `Get-ADUser` because members of the group could be users, computers or nested groups.

Comment: @Theo you're right, thank you!